# Take the content in the clipboard and store it in a string

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is my first time using VB in word. I entered the following code in the VB editor I loaded from Microsoft Word. I pasted the code from a website, assuming it would work. My understanding is that the code will take the content in the clipboard and store it in a string. But when I click run, I get the following error message

> "Compile error: User-defined type not defined"

The code I have in my editor is as follows:

```
Sub ClipboardTest()
'
' ClipboardTest Macro
'
'
Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim strClip As String

Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.GetFromClipboard
strClip = MyData.GetText
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Set a reference to Microsoft Forms 2 in the editor options for this; if you cannot find it just add a user form to your project and it will be added.

Comment: Of course, if you just want plain text from the website, you don't need the DataObject approach. Simply copy it & use .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText